# Issues applying styles in Breadcrumb NavXT plugin for Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, breadcrumbs

I am having enormous problems applying my styles to the Breadcrumb NavXT plugin.

When I apply the styles to the plugin in the WP document using the Breadcrumb NavXT plugin the last piece of text is always covered by the preceding colored arrow.

I have tried the obvious answers like apply margin-right to the last-child but nothing is working. Would really be grateful for some help.

Here is the relevant html that WP is outputting:

```
<!-- Breadcrumb NavXT 3.9.0 -->
<a title="Go to Blog." href="http://www.media.co.uk/wp">Blog</a> &gt; 
<a title="Go to Email &#038; SMS Broadcasting." href="http://www.media.co.uk/wp/  
email-sms-broadcasting/">Email &#038; SMS Broadcasting</a> &gt; Data List  
Management        </div><!--END breadcrumb -->
```

Here is the relevant css:

```
.breadcrumb{ list-style:none; overflow:hidden; position:absolute; font:10px    
Helvetica,Arial,Sans-Serif; top:160px; float:left}

.breadcrumb a{ color:white;  text-decoration:none;  padding:2px 0 2px 35px;     
background:blue; background:#728c8c; position:relative;  display:block; float:left}

.breadcrumb a:after{ content:"";  display:block;  width:0;  height:0;  
border-top:50px solid transparent;   border-bottom:50px solid transparent;  border-   
left:30px solid #728c8c;  position:absolute;  top:50%;  margin-top:-50px;  left:100%;  
z-index:2}

.breadcrumb a:before{ content:"";  display:block;  width:0;  height:0;  border- 
top:50px solid transparent;  border-bottom:50px solid transparent;  border-left:30px   
solid white;  position:absolute;  top:50%;  margin-top:-50px;  margin-left:1px;  
left:100%;  z-index:1}
.breadcrumb a:first-child { padding-left:10px;}

.breadcrumb a:nth-child(2) {background: #768c72}
.breadcrumb a:nth-child(2):after{border-left-color:#768c72}
.breadcrumb a:nth-child(3) {background: #909673}
.breadcrumb a:nth-child(3):after{border-left-color:#909673}
.breadcrumb a:nth-child(4) {background: #ad7601}
.breadcrumb a:nth-child(4):after{border-left-color:#ad7601}
.breadcrumb a:nth-child(5) {background: #E3E8E8}
.breadcrumb a:nth-child(5):after{border-left-color:#E3E8E8}
.breadcrumb a:nth-child(6) {background: #728c8c}
.breadcrumb a:nth-child(6):after{border-left-color:#728c8c}
.breadcrumb a:nth-child(7) {background: #768c72}
.breadcrumb a:nth-child(7):after{border-left-color:#768c72}
.breadcrumb a:last-child a{background:transparent !important;  color:black;  
pointer-events:none; cursor:default;}
.breadcrumb  a:hover{background:#526476}
.breadcrumb  a:hover:after{border-left-color:#526476 !important}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap `Data List Management` in a `span` and then add the css:

```
.breadcrumb span {
    float: right;
    padding: 2px 0 2px 20px;
}
```

You can change `float: right` to `display: inline` but that would not work in IE7. You could also change it to `float: left` - which is probably better - but this seems to cause issues with the `&gt;` HTML.

#### Edit

According to the [Breadcrumb NavXT Documentation](http://mtekk.us/code/breadcrumb-navxt/breadcrumb-navxt-doc/3/#advanced_use), you can use the following code to wrap your current element item in a span:

```
//Set the current item to be surrounded by a span element
$breadcrumb_trail->opt['current_item_prefix'] = '<span>';
//Set the suffix to close the span tag
$breadcrumb_trail->opt['current_item_suffix'] = '</span>';
```